# Laravel sum and seperate the negative and positive as value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
id | member_id | amount
========================
1  | 5   | -1000
2  | 3   | 400
3  | 2   | -102
4  | 1   | 220
5  | 10  | -10
```

**My code**

```
$getalltotal = MemberInfo::select('amount')
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();

        foreach ($getalltotal as $key => $value) {
            $negative = 0;
            $positive = 0;
            
            if (strpos($value['amount'], '-') !== false) {
                $negative += $value['amount'];
            } else {
                $positive += $value['amount'];
            }
            
            $total = $positive + $negative;
            $dataa[] = array(
                'positive' => $positive,
                'negative' => $negative,
                'total'    => $total,
            );
           
        }
```

I want to loop all the data and count to get a total of positive and negative amounts, but I not able to get it. The above my code it returns me 5 rows of it. Anyone can help with this :(?

### Final Data

```
$positive: 620
$negative: -1112
$total: 492
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put init code and final total calculus into the loop:

```
$negative = 0;
$positive = 0;

foreach ($getalltotal as $key => $value) {
    $amount = $value['amount'];

    if ($amount < 0) {
        $negative += $amount;
    } else {
        $positive += $amount;
    }
}

$total = $positive + $negative;
$data = array(
    'positive' => $positive,
    'negative' => $negative,
    'total'    => $total,
);
```

By doing like you did, `$negative` and `$positive` were constantly reset to `0`, and the final array was an array of arrays, because you added square brackets `$data[] = ...`.

It is also useless (and unproductive) to use a string function like `strpos()` in your case: you are working with numbers, so you can use number operators (in this case, the `<` comparison operator).